# how to set X-Frame-Options and X-XSS-Protection header in Caucho Resin web server

Tags: security, x-frame-options, resin

I have [caucho Resin web server](https://caucho.com/products/resin), I need set `X-Frame-Options` and `X-XSS-Protection` header for security, But I can not find any document to explain how to do it

I want to get the correct `resin.xml` , which include `X-XSS-Protection` and `X-Frame-Options`

Comment: You should challenge that requirement by asking what security enhancement X-XSS-Protection gives: https://caniuse.com/?search=X-XSS-Protection. X-Frame-Options is also better implemented using Content Security Policy frame-ancestors.